# unable to import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions

Tags: cucumber

Instead I am getting import `io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;` with which my program works fine but does not understand why I am not getting option to import

```
cucumber.api.CucumberOptions
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of cucumber are you using? Cucumber-jvm moved to io.cucumber package while ago.

Comment: I am also not able to import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions and also cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

Comment: Great Thanks for your response. Below are the dependencies I am using: <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
<version>1.0.6</version>

<artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
<version>5.3.0</version>